# Best and the worst case time complexity for 4 nested 'for' loops?

Tags: c, algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity, nested-loops

What is the worst and the best time complexity for nested `for` loop?

```
int compare(int n, int A[][]) {
    int i, j, k, m;
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            for (k=1; k<=n; k++) {
                for (m=1; m<=n; m++) {
                    if (A[i][j] == A[k][m] && !(i==k && j==m))
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

I tried to solve it on my own but getting really confused on how the inner most loop will add to the complexity.

Comment: Aside: in C arrays are rarely indexed from `1`. It is usual to index arrays from `0` such as `for(i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: Did you mean `!(i==k || j==m)`? That is more difficult to get your head around than `if (A[i][j] == A[k][m] && i != k && j != m)`

Comment: I meant `not` for both `i == k` and `j == m` leading to condition where both the conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best case: O(1), when A[1][1] = A[1][2]

Worst case: O(n<sup>4</sup>), when there is no repeated element -> you end up iterating whole array for each element of it.

Note that you could implement it more efficiently with a map or a set (will call it structure):

- Iterate the array
- If the structure already has A[i][j], return 1
- Add A[i][j] to the structure
- return 0 after array iteration ends

This will give you a worse case of O(n<sup>2</sup> log n) or O(n<sup>2</sup>), depending on the structure you use

Comment: Thanks @Srini and juvian Do you think by changing the logic the efficiency could be improved instead of using a map or set?

Comment: @RajatGupta not sure what you mean. Using a map or a set already means changing the logic

Comment: I meant in terms of the looping. But now I got your point. :)

Comment: For best case in the solution you and @Srini gave, `i != k` should be satisfied along with `j != m`. Therefore, A[1][1] = A[1][2] is not correct. Does it make sense or I'm making it more confusing?

Comment: @RajatGupta !(i==k && j==m) is equivalent to (i != k || j !=m)

Comment: Okay, got it. I didn't took into consideration `&&` condition. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The best case time complexity is constant, `O(1)`. Best case will happen when the first and second element of the grid `A` are equal.

```
    1 1 x x x
A = x x x x x
    x x x x x
    x x x x x
```

The worst case complexity is `O(n^4)`. Worst case will happen when all the elements of the grid `A` are unique.

```
    1  2  3  4
A = 5  6  7  8
    9  10 11 12
    13 14 15 16
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaidul That's what I had in mind but thought it was correct.